# Firebase Java Save a file from firebase storage and know the save path to external memory

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to save a storage image from url and bucket like so:

```
private void downloadFile() {
    
            uri.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    String url = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
                    // Create a storage reference from our app
                    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
    
    // Or Create a reference to a file from a Google Cloud Storage URI
                    StorageReference gsReference =
                            storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://pophome-62bf8.appspot.com/" + url);
    
    
                    /*In this case we'll use this kind of reference*/
    //Download file in Memory
                    StorageReference islandRef = storageRef.child(url);
    
                    final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
                    islandRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
                      @Override
                      public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                       }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                            // Handle any errors
                        }
                    });
    
    
    
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    
                }
    
            });
    
    
    
        }
```

But I don't know how to use those bytes to get an image. Could someone please show me how I can use FileOutputStream to write my bytes?

Comment: The file is not saved at all as you do nothing with the bytes[] of onSuccess. You can save those bytes where you want.

Comment: @blackapps How can I do?

Comment: I do not understand the problem. Write those bytes to a file. A very standard task/action.

Comment: @blackapps I'm a newbie to Android Java so I don't know how to write those bytes to a file

Comment: @blackapps Since there is no BufferedImage on the android sdk I don't know what to use

Comment: You only need a FileOutputStream where you write your bytes to. No need for a BufferedImage.

Comment: @blackapps I don't know how to use it

Comment: @blackapps YES, already done. I didn't find anything, that's why I wrote here about stackoverflow

Comment: `About 22.800.000 results (0,51 seconds) `

Answer (score 0):

In your firebase console ,select your project ,under selected project select storage from left side menu to know about saved images.

[image]

Comment: I think you don't understand the question. I was trying to save the image having the bytes downloaded not looking for the path from the firebase